# Writing an R function that outputs maximum likelihood estimates?

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix-decomposition

How would I write an R function that takes a response vec y and covariate matrix X and outputs a vector of maximum likelihood estimates of coefficients β where μ = Xβ And E[Y] = μ, where Y is an exponentially distributed random vector?

I can use the qr() and related functions, and need to program the iteratively reweighted least-squares algorithm from first principles using the QR decomposition.

Comment: Questions about how to code in `R` are off topic here. They can be on topic on [SO] but they will ask to see the code you've tried already. They don't welcome pure 'give me the code' questions.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There are already functions that do this for you in R, & there is `optim` when you need something custom.

Comment: It generally involves some use of the optim() (or similar type of) function.  Here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126650/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-relationship-between-coefficients-in-logistic-regressi/126669#126669 is one example of a hand coded ML function in R for a completely different type of problem.  The general methodology is the same though...you minimize the negative log likelihood function.